# How can I remove windows title bar or customize it in compose desktop?

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application, compose-desktop

I want to remove windows default title bar so I can create my own that matches my application. I searched around but couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove it you can use `undecorated` argument for `Window`:

```
fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        undecorated = true,
    ) {
        App()
    }
}
```